# Can ProGuard remove conditional code from a method that ALWAYS returns a constant?

Tags: android, optimization, proguard

On my Android application I've been using conditional code like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // do something...
}
```

And if ProGurad evalutes `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to false, the block of code inside the `if` is stripped from the final bytecode. Which is working as intended.

However, with the introduction of the new build system for Android, we now have many abilities we didn't have before. I'm taking advantage of that by creating a new `buildType` which I call it **QA**. With that I've add a `BuildConfig.QA` constant that will be true or false accordingly to the build type.

Now I have some pieces of code where I need to test if it's a `DEBUG` or a `QA` build, like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG || BuildConfig.QA) {
    // do something...
}
```

But this is cumbersome to write all over the place. Instead, I've decided to create a static method on my utils class, like this:

```
public static boolean isDevelopmentBuild() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG || BuildConfig.QA;
}
```

The problem is that with this approach, any conditional code will not be removed as it used to be. Before, ProGuard could evaluate those constants to false and strip the code. Now, it has to call a method and check for the return value.

But since the return value of that method are constants, is it possible that ProGuard could evaluate the method call in a way that would know that the return value is always a constant value (during runtime) and remove the code from the final bytecode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not add a constant DEV to your BuildConfig interface, like

```
boolean DEBUG = ...
boolean QA = ...
boolean DEV = DEBUG | QA;
```

It will be a compile-time constant (given that DEBUG and QA are defined at compile-time) and so ProGuard will be able to do code elimination based on just

```
if (BuildConfig.DEV) { ...
```

Comment: Interesting solution, never thought of that. My only "issue" with such approach is because I'm using Android Studio which has this inspection (from IntelliJ IDEA base code) which gives me the following warning: _Condition '!BuildConfig.DEV' is always 'false'_. If I just use `BuildConfig.DEV`, I don't get the warning, I only get it when I use the `!` before, which sometimes I need to. I could disable the inspection but I really didn't want to because it might be useful for other scenarios.

Comment: Also, didn't you mean to say `DEBUG || QA` (double pipe)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC, IntelliJ has a "@noinspect" annotation that you can apply to code to turn off inspections at particular points. And no, I actually meant "|", which for `boolean`s is a non-short-circuiting equivalent to `||`. There's no real reason to use it rather than || here -- just aesthetics!

Comment: I believe you are talking about the `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` inspection for this particular case. But this only works at method level. For statements, I would need to add this comment `//noinspection ConstantConditions` and I'm not really a fan of having all these comments all over the place. But it seems that the warning is only displayed when using the `!` operator. So, I could create enough constants to check for all the scenarios I need without using the `!` operator. In this case, I would just need to add `RELEASE` constant to `BuildConfig`.

Comment: I'll wait 1 day or 2 and see if Eric (ProGuard's developer) has any more insight on this and a possible, different, solution. Otherwise, I'll just mark this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

ProGuard should be able to inline the method and remove your debugging code. You can fairly easily check that with a Dalvik bytecode disassembler like `dexdump` or with a decompiler.

Ernest Friedman-Hill's solution is probably preferable though. It is actually the javac compiler that already removes code that is guarded by a constant boolean flag that is set to `false`. It saves some processing and you don't need to rely on ProGuard. Again, you can check the result with a disassembler or a decompiler.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight.